How to put reference to external data in API input
This may be one example of a very general design question. Suppose I am building a service and I want the client to provide the location of some data on S3 which I will then read and process.
How do I decide between these options:

Client provides full URL to the S3 object.
Client provides an ID or partial path, and I have the base path come from configuration.

My intuition is that #2 is better. The data is not private, so I can already assume my service will need to have the appropriate credentials to access the data. So it's not like it can reasonably accept any old S3 URL.

If you start off by sharing full S3 object URLs, that's a one-way door that might be hard to walk back (clients will be built on the assumption that they can use it directly, and you'd break them if you change that). Can you elaborate on who your clients are? End users, or other services that you control?

That's a good point. The clients here are other services internal to the company.

I see some relevant aspects:
Modelling
I'd strongly recommend to implement one common way of representing links to data sources, and to use that very same representation through all your services and applications.
You mention three candidates (if I understand correctly), each with different tradeoffs:

a full URL
a partial path within some well-known, configured base URL
an ID to be inserted into a URL template

Whatever you choose as your representation, make sure it is used all over your system (and not just for one API of this one service), eliminating the need to do confusing and error-prone transformations.
Security
Using a URL provided from the client opens the door to various kinds of attack. You should at least include a syntax check that blocks unwanted types of URL.
Using a partial path still allows for injection of malicious syntax, unless you do syntax checks in your code.
Using a numerical ID avoids (most of?) these risks.
Flexibility
Using a URL allows your service to operate on any data, wherever it comes from. E.g. it even allows you to combine S3 data with sources outside of S3.
Using a partial path limits your service to data within some sub-path of one configured base URL. While the configured base path allows you switch over to a different provider, you can't do cross-provider tasks. And, when the need arises to switch to a different base URL, then probably the partial paths also no longer match, and have to be updated as well. And you always have to keep in mind what the base path is, so you know what to encode into the partial path. (Been there, done that...)
Using just a numerical ID implies that all data sources reside in a common base, and just the final path component differs. This is the least flexible schema. Or, you put flexibility into the (hopefully) one place that resolves IDs to real URLs, e.g. by maintaining an integer-index table of relevant data URLs.
Opinion
Of your three candidates, personally I'd go for URLs, and have a configurable URL validator that allows only the URL patterns that you currently need.
This allows you to treat URLs as opaque entities in most parts of your system, and have only the URL-resolver check for validity. If the need arises to add more locations/providers/whatever, it's just the validity check that you have to update/reconfigure.
But of course, your project priorities might be different, guiding you in a different direction.

The immediate concern I had was security. Can you trust any old URL that the client provides? Does the client trust the people they have working for them?
It's not clear what you mean by "client" but generally this means "end user." I would be weary of accepting any URL and then doing any sort of downstream processing. Treat this as you would any other used input: be suspicious and put in guards to ensure the integrity of your system and your customers. You'll need to find a balance between "any old URL" and limiting options for your end users. Since you are processing files provided by end users, virus scanning is a must.
It would be best to constrain the data format used in these files. Reject any file that doesn't conform as an easy way to detect obvious compromises. You might even consider isolating the processes or machines that do the processing, so infected or corrupted files don't pose a risk for the rest of your ecosystem.

Thanks for raising security as a concern. In this case, by client I meant another service internal to the company.

That an depends on where that other service got the files, too. Don't fully trust internal stuff either. And if the files are generated internally, was and data on those files generated externally? Security can still be a concern.

Greg Burghardt raises a valid point about security, however it sounds like your app is going to process some random blob of data (which you don't have control over), if that is a business requirement. You should separate the security concerns into two groups:

Things you need to do because you are processing a random blob of data.
Things related to how you are transferring the data.

With respect to the transfer method (taking a random URL), S3 has a set of known endpoints, additionally clients can create a DNS CNAME from a custom domain to one of the known endpoints. Therefore you have some options for validating the URL:

You could whitelist the known S3 endpoints and reject anything else.
Or add some code to resolve the DNS back to a known endpoint.

It's still possible someone could give you a URL to content hosted on S3 that belongs to someone else, however if all your are doing is a standard S3 GET request and you have reasonable limits:

Total number of retries.
Time between retries.
Total number of request per hour per customer.

I can't see an obvious way for someone to benefit / exploit that, so it may make sense to keep things simple and just take the URL (with appropriate checks as outlined above).
Note: With respect to providing credentials, if you take the full URL that would also allow the providing service to sign the URL so your service doesn't need credentials to access.
